# How can i prevent a dependecy from being compiled in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Im working with flutter_maps and flutter_map_tile_caching, in mobile it all works just fine but in web the build process fails in that dependency. I want to do caching of the map tiles only in android for offline use, i dont want that behaviour in web, is there anyway to block this?

My Error:
`/home/roberto/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_map_tile_caching-8.0.1/lib/src/db/defs/metadata.g.dart:18:8: Error: The integer literal 8585861370448577604 can't be represented exactly in JavaScript. Try changing the literal to something that can be represented in JavaScript. In JavaScript 8585861370448577536 is the nearest value that can be represented exactly. id: -8585861370448577604, ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /home/roberto/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_map_tile_caching-8.0.1/lib/src/db/defs/recovery.g.dart:18:8: Error: The integer literal 8117814053675000476 can't be represented exactly in JavaScript. Try changing the literal to something that can be represented in JavaScript. In JavaScript 8117814053675000832 is the nearest value that can be represented exactly. id: -8117814053675000476, ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...` 
These are some of the errors, they are all like this, because the dependecy doesnt support web, thats why i wonder if there is anyway to prevent this library only for web.

I tried to use the kIsWeb to check if the platform is web, but this only works at runtime, not compile time.

Comment: Conditional imports: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-packages#conditionally-importing-and-exporting-library-files

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible, as stated by the author in this link: https://github.com/JaffaKetchup/flutter_map_tile_caching/issues/96.

> This is a major oversight on my part. Of course FMTC isn't intended
> for use on web, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't compile. The issue
> lies with the reliance on Isar, which uses a code generator to
> generate type safe database models. The current workaround is to use
> conditional imports. But, as stated by the author of Isar in
> [dart-lang/sdk#50385](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/50385), they are cumbersome to use. There is a proposal
> for conditionally imported libraries at [dart-lang/language#2235](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2235), but I
> doubt that will be merged any time soon. For the time being, I'll have
> to look into conditional imports, but that might take a while (major
> refactoring). For now, I'm afraid you'll have to stick to v6, my
> apologies. I'll try to have this resolved by the end of the week, but
> I am extremely busy at the moment. Thanks for your patience!